# End file parsing (Java)

Tags: java, compiler-errors, linked-list

I'm wondering where the error is in this situation.

As you can see below there are several classes that have been implemented but when I started to run it always send "end file parsing error"

```
class Provider {
    int ID;
    String name;
    String typeOfItems;
    public Provider(int i, String n, String items) {
        ID = i;
        name = n;
        typeOfItems = items;
    }
    public void printProvider() {
        System.out.print("The provider ID is " + ID
              + "the cliend name is" + name + "the type of items he is selling is "
              + typeOfItems);
    }
}
class LinkedList {
    Node head;
    class Node {
        Provider data;
        Node next;
        Node(Provider d) {
            data = d;
            next = null;
        }
    }

    public void push(Provider new_data) {

        Node new_node = new Node(new_data);

        new_node.next = head;

        head = new_node;
    }
    /* Inserts a new node after the given prev_node. */
    public void insertAfter(Node prev_node, Provider new_data) {
        /* 1. Check if the given Node is null */
        if (prev_node == null) {
            System.out.println("The given previous node cannot be null");
            return;
        }

        Node new_node = new Node(new_data);

        new_node.next = prev_node.next;

        prev_node.next = new_node;
    }

    /* Appends a new node at the end. This method is
    defined inside LinkedList class shown above */
    public void append(Provider new_data) {

        Node new_node = new Node(new_data);

        new_node.next = null;

        Node last = head;
        while (last.next != null)
            last = last.next;
        last.next = new_node;
        return;
    }
    public void printList() {
        Node tnode = head;
        while (tnode != null) {
            tnode.data.printProvider();
            tnode = tnode.next;
        }
    }
    void deleteNode(int id) {

        Node temp = head, prev = null;

        if (temp != null && temp.data.ID == id) {
            head = temp.next;
            return;
        }
        while (temp != null) {
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp.next;
        }

        if (temp == null)
            return;
        prev.next = temp.next;
    }

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            LinkedList providerList = new LinkedList();

            Provider P1 = new Provider(1, "Rabeb", "Books");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please be a tiny bit more specific than " it always send "end file parsing error"". [Edit] your question to include the full error message that you get. Also: correcting your indentation (or better yet: letting your IDE do that) would make the code more readable and will *likely* also make the problem more obvious (which I suspect is unmatched braces).

Comment: Please properly format and indent your code. The most likely cause for the error is that your curly braces are not properly paired, but in the code's current form it's very difficult to check if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

You've got syntax errors in your code. I hope you have an IDE that has formatting and error reporting abilities. If not, address that first.

This error occurs when your code has more opening braces than closing ones, for example. Assuming you copy/pasted correctly: Your `LinkedList` class is missing its closing brace.